# How to store Azure Ad Instance in environment variable or azure key vault

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, environment-variables, azure-keyvault, .net-core-3.1

My app is authenticating user via Azure Ad. I have stored the Azure Ad info in appsettings.json but I do not want to keep it here. I tried to store these values in environment variable but got error as "OptionsValidationException: The 'Instance' option must be provided."

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "test.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "9dasdasb677-dsadsa5ad-asdd83-aa73-7dcdsadsa80bc7",
    "ClientId": "9dasdasb677-dsadsa5ad-asdd83-aa73-7dcdsadsa80bc7",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  }
}
```

**startup.cs**

```
public void ConfigureServices (IServiceCollection services) {
            services.AddAuthentication (AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddAzureAD (options => Configuration.Bind ("AzureAd", options));

            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext> (options =>
                options.UseSqlServer (
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString ("DefaultConnection")));

            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser> (options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext> ();

}
```

Am I missing something in startup file or something else.
If I want to store the values from appsettings.json file to azure key vault, then what will be the format of data. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you called the environment variables, but the environment variable name would have to be like this AzureAD__Instance
note the double underscore (__) indicates nested. because the config is looking for instance under the azureAD nest. 
I believe if you use the prefix ASPNETCORE_AzureAD__Instance in your env variables, the appsettings.json will overwrite it if it also exists in appsettings.json. so if you did with the aspnetcore prefix remember to remove the tree from appsettings.json.

as for doing with keyvault, you would do something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/key-vault-configuration?view=aspnetcore-3.1#use-managed-identities-for-azure-resources

hopefully that points you in the right direction.

Comment: One thing to note with that link is that they expect the Key Vault to use double dashes instead of double underscores like the environment variables.